# Am I being jealous over my kitten?

Tags: cats

So, a little backstory first: this is *my* first pet. I've had dogs growing up and, for whatever reason, whenever we got a new pet it was always my siblings'. Whether it hamster, rat, bird, or puppy, somehow I never was apart of the "picking out the pet" process nor naming it- though, as the eldest child, I was always the one taking care of it.

So, I graduated college recently and landed a dream job back in my hometown where my grandparents are located. I had always told myself that once I landed my first "real job", I'd get myself my first true pet. I ended up deciding on a gorgeous and adorable Bengal. The adoption period of waiting the 12 weeks for her (to come of 12-weeks of age) was absolute hell in anticipation and but it was definitely worth it.

I've had her for three weeks and she's amazing. We go on car trips together, to the park, I play with her constantly, etc. And of course, other than the money, vet fees, and playing with her at least 2-3 hours a day after work (she has so much energy!), I've spent an earnest 50+ hours from before I had adopted her (in making my decision), waiting for her to come of age, and even once I got her in research. From dieting to play, to psychology and positive reinforcement- I've researched it all to be the best pet-parent possible.

A few days ago, I dropped her off at my grandparents so that they could take care of her while I pack my apartment up. There's going to be a lot of heavy lifting and coming in-and-out of the apartment, so it really wasn't the best place for a playful kitten to be around. Now, I've taken her to the house a few times already so she's familiar with them and my family. I also wanted her to get adjusted because I'm actually going to rent a room from my grandparents because it's mutually beneficial (I save money to pay off school loans and they get a sizable rent check for one room); just for a year or so.

Well, in the few days that I've been away, my grandparents have absolutely fallen in love with her. Which I'm glad! Except... it's been all fine-and-dandy but I'm a bit taken back by some of the things my grandmother has said.

First, let me preface that one should get the stereotype of typical old people out of their mind ASAP. These are young folks who play Pokemon Go, watch my nephew on the daily, and are always out and about. So it's not like they sit at home "bored". My grandmother has wanted a pet for YEARS and my grandfather has sternly said no because he didn't want to clean up after it. My cat is okay in his book because it's not his problem (aka mess). Additionally, while my grandmother is the sweetest person I've ever met, she's also very... manipulative? cunning? She convinces my grandfather year after year to spend thousands on new iPads, iPhones, fancy vacations, etc. She get's what she wants and I've seen her pull some shady tactics to do so. A pet is the *only* thing she's wanted over the years that she hasn't gotten.

So, here's where my story comes in: in the few days that I've been gone, she's sent me tons of texts about how much my grandfather loves the cat and how much bonding time they've had. She's sent me 18 pictures and only *one* has been of my cat alone. The rest are of my kitten cuddling on my grandfather's bare chest in bed in the morning or my kitten cuddling with my grandmother.

Then today, as my grandparents are leaving for vacation and I'm heading back home, my grandmother and I have this texting conversation:

> Grandma: I will miss her. Ha
>
> Me: Yeah, she's such a cuddle bug.
>
> Grandma: She likes to join you when going to the bathroom. Ha.

(I'm thinking in my head uhhhh TMI? I don't want to think of my precious, innocent kitten sitting with my grandma while she takes a dump lol)

> Me: Is grandpa all packed yet?
>
> Grandma: Ha yep
>
> Me: He just didn't want to leave the kitty :P
>
> Grandma: Probably. He is pretty smitten by her
>
> Me: Poor guy is gonna have his heart broken when I take move out :P
>
> Grandma: No cause she is staying. Ha ha
>
> Me: Haha nooooope. She was too expensive lol

(As a male, I can't admit that I love her to death so I make a financial joke instead)

> Grandma: No, she's our Christmas give from you. ha ha
>
> Me: Maybe I'll get you one of your own but she's mine! lol
>
> Grandma: But we love her!
>
> Me: So do I!
>
> Grandma: But you left her. Ha

(This is where I felt I was either being jealous or sensitive. This isn't a funny joke to me. I left her for a FEW days so I could pack my apartment without my kitten getting hurt/in the way and I had mentioned a few times to my grandmother that I felt so guilty for leaving my kitten and really missed her. "But you left her".. I just don't find that funny but actually mean)

> Me: Well she goes back in my room when I get back :O
>
> Grandma: We will see... Ha ha

Am I being too sensitive? I feel like she is passively aggressively trying to take my cat or implying that they she wants my cat. I have a feeling this may present issues when I move in, such as them feeding my cat treats whenever or acting like she's theirs. I understand a good argument is "their house, their rules" so to suck it up, except I paying good money for rent.

Am I okay feeling like the "But you left her" and "We will see" line is a bit too much?

Comment: I think this is too based on your family dynamics and your grandma as a person for anyone to answer properly. Bottom line from myself, stop beating around the bush. Next time she brings it up you let her know the cat is yours and will continue to be yours and only yours, but don't be rude about it. The cat is your property and rightfully yours to do with as you please, I understand you do not want to cause issue with your grandparents but i believe people should be open about their concerns, not dance around the issue. You will be living with these people and you need to set clear boundaries.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's really about your relationship with your grandmother. It might be on topic at the Parenting stack exchange.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to say without knowing all the individuals, but this sounds like standard grandparent teasing plus a few normal cat behaviors (many cats insist on following humans into the bathroom unless locked out -- I keep telling mine "do I follow *you* into the litterbox?" but they don't accept that objection. One has been known to try to stand on my shoulders while I'm busy.)

Don't create a problem where one isn't necessary. They really aren't going to steal your baby, or your baby's affections. Relax. Especially since cats are quite clever enough to deliberately play off their humans against each other to get more attention.